# Multiple ScriptTemplateViewResolvers in Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, template-engine

I want to use two different template view resolvers in my Spring mvc app. For example, kotlin and javascript at the same time.
Creation of 2 ViewResolver beans is not the problem.
It seems impossible to use two ScriptTemplateConfigurer because ScriptTemplateConfig is being acquired in [ScriptTemplateView.autodetectViewConfig](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b503e4679ce37ac099be668cc1e33705da3fead1/spring-web-reactive/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/view/script/ScriptTemplateView.java#L261-L271) by ScriptTemplateConfig.class from Spring context.

Is there a way to use two scripting engines at the same time or this feature is not supported currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently scriptTemplateConfig is taken from context, so there is no way to force ScriptTemplateView to use specific ScriptTemplateConfigurer.

But this can be overriden easily by adding property scriptTemplateConfig  to ScriptTemplateView. So here is the custom ScriptTemplateView:

```
public class MyScriptTemplateView extends ScriptTemplateView {

    private ScriptTemplateConfig scriptTemplateConfig;

    public void setScriptTemplateConfig(ScriptTemplateConfig scriptTemplateConfig) {
        this.scriptTemplateConfig = scriptTemplateConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected ScriptTemplateConfig autodetectViewConfig() throws BeansException {
        ScriptTemplateConfig res = scriptTemplateConfig;
        if (res == null) {
            res = super.autodetectViewConfig();
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Another enhancement that is needed is setting scriptTemplateConfig to this view. I'm doing this in custom view resolver and setting it to view on creation:

```
public class MyScriptTemplateViewResolver extends ScriptTemplateViewResolver {

    private ScriptTemplateConfig scriptTemplateConfig;

    public void setScriptTemplateConfig(ScriptTemplateConfig scriptTemplateConfig) {
        this.scriptTemplateConfig = scriptTemplateConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName) throws Exception {
        MyScriptTemplateView view = (MyScriptTemplateView) super.buildView(viewName);
        view.setScriptTemplateConfig(scriptTemplateConfig);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> requiredViewClass() {
        return MyScriptTemplateView.class;
    }

}
```

Finally, we can use this stuff by passing configurer to ViewResolver:

```
@Bean
public ScriptTemplateConfigurer kotlinConfigurer() {
    ScriptTemplateConfigurer configurer = new ScriptTemplateConfigurer();
    configurer.setEngineName("kotlin");
    configurer.setScripts("scripts/render.kts");
    configurer.setRenderFunction("render");
    configurer.setSharedEngine(false);
    return configurer;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver kotlinViewResolver(ScriptTemplateConfigurer kotlinConfigurer) {
    MyScriptTemplateViewResolver viewResolver = new MyScriptTemplateViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".kts");
    viewResolver.setScriptTemplateConfig(kotlinConfigurer);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

You can check a sample [in the repo](https://github.com/melgene/kotlin-script-templating/commit/970ddb1af294619b2a089e99bc19b4e768818bd3)